# Adjusting height of scroll ball in CSS

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

Is it possible to adjust the height of the scrollbar here?

I've used overflow-y:auto and it seems to be starting from the header and up until the bottom and when I scroll, the header also goes along with it.

1. Need to fix the header
2. Need to adjust the height of scroll bar and make it scroll only a sub div

HTML:

```
<div class="notifications-window">
    <div class="notifications-header">
        <h4>Notifications</h4>
        <button type="button"><i class="far fa-window-close close-window"></i></button>
    </div>
    <div class="notification-details">
        <p>Congratulations! Login Reward: 2 credits</p>
        <p>Congratulations! Login Reward: 2 credits</p>
        <p>Congratulations! Login Reward: 2 credits</p>
        <p>Congratulations! Login Reward: 2 credits</p>
        <p>Congratulations! Login Reward: 2 credits</p>
        <p>Congratulations! Login Reward: 2 credits</p>
        <p>Congratulations! Login Reward: 2 credits</p>
        <p>Congratulations! Login Reward: 2 credits</p>
        <p>Congratulations! Login Reward: 2 credits</p>
        <p>Congratulations! Login Reward: 2 credits</p>
        <p>Congratulations! Login Reward: 2 credits</p>
        <p>Congratulations! Login Reward: 2 credits</p>
        <p>Congratulations! Login Reward: 2 credits</p>
        <p>Congratulations! Login Reward: 2 credits</p>
        <p>Congratulations! Login Reward: 2 credits</p>
        <p>Congratulations! Login Reward: 2 credits</p>
        <p>Congratulations! Login Reward: 2 credits</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.notifications-window {
border: 3px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
color: #fff;
border-collapse: collapse;
border-radius: 5px;
text-align: center;
width: 350px;
list-style-type: none;
display: inline-block;
}

.notifications-window {
height: 400px;
}


.notifications-window p {
font-size: small;
padding: 5px;
background: rgb(141, 136, 136);
border-radius: 5px;
margin: 5px;
}


.notifications-header h4 {
display: inline-block;
width: 90%;
}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/EEY5f.png

Comment: Please, take some time to read [ask] and provide a [mcve].

Comment: overscroll-behavior: contain; overflow-y: scroll; try putting this in the div you want to have scroll

Comment: Hey colin, I've tried adding that, but didn't work... i've included the current html and css code in my main post, can you please have a look at it and suggest as to where I should be putting those?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to remove the style, because you adding on the entire section which is not needed, also not works:

```
.notifications-window {
  height: 400px;
}
```

Add this style, so to scroll the sub div only, also height is required always if we are using scroll related styling on that basis it'll add scroll:

```
.notification-details {
  overflow-y: auto;
  max-height: 300px; //change height as per you need/requirement
}
```

Hopefully, this will help you out/meet your requirement.

[image: Please refer the screenshot for clarity]

Comment: Great... Go ahead :)